# put less values to a bigger 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array that I initialize like this: `int[][] mat = new int [10][10]`. Then I'm asking the user how many rows and cols he want. For example he insert `row=3, col=4`.
How can I work with this size ([3][4]) so I won't see all the zeros? I just want to insert 12 values to an 100 values array.

```
int[][] mat = new int[10][10];
int row, col;

do {
    System.out.println("enter rows: ");
    row = s.nextInt();
    if (row > 10) {
        System.out.println("value should be between 1-10, try again ");
    }
} while (row > 10);

do {
    System.out.println("enter cols: ");
    col = s.nextInt();
    if (col > 10) {
        System.out.println("value should be between 1-10, try again ");
    }
} while (col > 10);

mat[10][10] = mat[10 - 10 + row][10 - 10 + col];
System.out.println("enter: " + row * col + " values");
for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
        mat[i][j] = s.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about postponing the creation of the matrix:

```
int row, col;

do{
    System.out.println("enter rows: ");
    row = s.nextInt();
    if (row > 10){
        System.out.println("valuse should be between 1-10, try again ");
    }

}while(row > 10);

do{
    System.out.println("enter cols: ");
    col = s.nextInt();
    if (col > 10){
        System.out.println("valuse should be between 1-10, try again ");
    }

}while(col > 10);
int[][] mat = new int[rows][cols];//create matrix here
```

Note that by postponing the creation of the matrix, you *can* allow more than `10` rows or columns. If a person would enter `100` and your program doesn't refuse this, a matrix with `100` rows/columns can be created.

You should also check that the input is greater than (or equal to) zero. Have you ever seen a matrix with `-5` rows?

And this statement makes no sense at all:

```
mat[10][10] = mat[10-10+row][10-10+col];
```

It won't do any harm, since it is guaranteed that the bounds are correct, but it is useless since the values are initialized on `0`.

And a small spelling fix: It's *"values"*; not *"valuse"* as well as *"zeros"* (instead of *"zerows"*, unless you want to sound like a pirate of course ;).